# DblClick call in VBA - close on double click without running function

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon,

Bear with me,  I am new to VBA. I have a Sub that opens a text box when its double clicked, not only do I want it to open the text box (expands it), i also want it to run a sub called EMSpull. This all works perfectly except for the fact I want to then double click to close the textbox without running EMSpull again.

Also, can someone explain "Control", especially for this situation (i didnt write the adjustheight )

Code is below

```
Private Sub txtEMS_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call AdjustHeight(txtEMS, lblEMS)
Call EMSpull
End Sub


Public Sub AdjustHeight(cControl As Control, cLabel As Control)
On Error GoTo errhand

If bExpandedMode = False Then
      dOldTop = cControl.Top
    dOldLeft = cControl.Left
    dOldWidth = cControl.Width
    dOldHeight = cControl.Height
    cControl.Top = lblDescription.Top + 50
    cControl.Width = cControl.Width * 2
    cControl.Height = 500
    cControl.Left = lblResults.Left
    bExpandedMode = True
    Call HideAllTxt(cControl)
    lblDescription.Visible = True
    lblDescription.Caption = cLabel.Caption
    If Len(cControl.Text) > 2 Then
      cControl.CurLine = 0
    End If
Else
    bExpandedMode = False
    Call ShowAllTxt
    lblDescription.Visible = False
    cControl.Top = dOldTop
    cControl.Left = dOldLeft
    cControl.Width = dOldWidth
    cControl.Height = dOldHeight
End If
Exit Sub
errhand:
Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i would retool it to check for height and if height = x then perform this action or that action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a global boolean named bExpandedMode at the top of the subs? If so this should work fine:

```
Private Sub txtEMS_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call AdjustHeight(txtEMS, lblEMS)
if bExpandedMode = true then Call EMSpull 'Calls it only when it expanded in AdjustHeight
End Sub


Public Sub AdjustHeight(cControl As Control, cLabel As Control)
On Error GoTo errhand

If bExpandedMode = False Then
      dOldTop = cControl.Top
    dOldLeft = cControl.Left
    dOldWidth = cControl.Width
    dOldHeight = cControl.Height
    cControl.Top = lblDescription.Top + 50
    cControl.Width = cControl.Width * 2
    cControl.Height = 500
    cControl.Left = lblResults.Left
    bExpandedMode = True
    Call HideAllTxt(cControl)
    lblDescription.Visible = True
    lblDescription.Caption = cLabel.Caption
    If Len(cControl.Text) > 2 Then
      cControl.CurLine = 0
    End If
Else
    bExpandedMode = False
    Call ShowAllTxt
    lblDescription.Visible = False
    cControl.Top = dOldTop
    cControl.Left = dOldLeft
    cControl.Width = dOldWidth
    cControl.Height = dOldHeight
End If
Exit Sub
errhand:
Resume Next
End Sub
```

Basically if that boolean exists and is used like I think it is, it just check whether the box is expanded right now or not. When it's not, the boolean is False, and AdjustHeight expands it, then turns it to true. Conversely when it is set to True, it closes it instead, and sets it to False.

So my fix just checks that same boolean and only runs it 1 way (when it just expanded)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very simple. I wish i knew what the bExpandedMode meant! , now I do

Comment: Also a textbox is a type of Control. You send txtEMS as an argument when calling AdjustHeight. It simply tells that sub that it has to use the textbox. The sub basically keeps track of the current position of the textbox (`cControl.Top`) and the old position of the textbox (which was previously registered during `dOldTop = cControl.Top`) Then it formats it and makes it visible and all that.